# Excel - How to get value from location specified in different cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to retrieve value located in different spreadsheet which would be easy if I could link it.
But my links are partially build with formulas:

In cell a1 i have this:

```
="C:\spreadsheets\lists\shopping\"&C1&"\"&A5&"\"&P5&"\["&C2&" Shopping list March.xlsx]Data'!$GJ$7"
```

Then I would link to use it in b2 as value from this location (pointed above)

```
="C:\spreadsheets\lists\shopping\A\B\C\[Second Shopping list March.xlsx]Data'!$GJ$7"
```

But I cannot find solution how i can make it work as a link instead of text value i'm getting now.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: INDIRECT... but the other workbook needs to be open.

Comment: Thank you, but it will be problematic when i work with large amount of linked files. Hope to find other way around.

Comment: I'm not sure there is any other robust option.